# How to know the count of index in sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

Merging two indexes, and now I want to know the total number of docs, how can i do?

```
/usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --config /path/to/sphinx.conf --rotate --merge apps apps_delta
Sphinx 2.0.8-id64-release (r3831)
Copyright (c) 2001-2012, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2012, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/path/to/sphinx.conf'...
merging index 'apps_delta' into index 'apps'...
read 50.5 of 50.5 MB, 100.0% done
merged 85.2 Kwords
merged in 1.146 sec
total 6326 reads, 0.198 sec, 25.3 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 332 writes, 0.336 sec, 253.4 kb/call avg, 1.0 msec/call avg
rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=1862).
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `indextool --dumpheader`

Or just run a query that matches all documents and inspect `total_found`.

Or if you upgrade your sphinx version could use `SHOW INDEX STATUS`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-show-index-status